# How to load remote webpage on Android Hybrid App(the easy way)?

Tags: javascript, android, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap-desktop-app

I have decided to learn how to create Android APK on windows for personal/learning use (Not for Android Play).

My design plan is to load a remote HTML page on android app and allow user to click a few links and then app make a post request to an API to get m3u8 of the video and play it !I already created the HTML web page and have the API access.

So could you guys point me to a beginner tutorial/example and what software and tools I need and which one is easiest to start with (to achieve my design goal)? (I installed PhoneGap but not sure if that is the only tool I need and if it is the easiest path. So I wait for your advice).

Furthermore, does installing java JDK creates any security issues for my PC? (since I heard lots of bad news about Java in past few years.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are going with Phonegap, I would recommend you to first read the phonegap documentation so you can setup a basic phonegap project ([phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/)). I would recommend to implement the site functionality inside phonegap instead of just loading an external site; this way you have access to more phone controls than from a web browser. But if it is really a requirement to load the external site, basically, the phone gap would load an empty page that would load your external site using the cordova inappbrowser plugin, here is the github page of this project ([inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser)).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Could you explain a little what you mean by implementing the site functionality inside phonegap ?You mean putting the remote website as local asset inside Android Hybrid App?Furthermore, How i can make post request in phonegap to remote api ?Do you mean loading my remote website using iframe in empty page by phonegap ?

Comment: Yes, what I meant was implementing the site as they recommend on phonegap, not just opening a new url from the app (check the phonegap link docs), if you need to connect after that to another service you would need to include a way of communicating to the API, a way of do this would be with AJAX requests that returns you the data that you need. In case you still just want all the functionality on the external site simply add a link as documented in the inappbrowser link that I posted.

Comment: May i know how to install cordova-plugin-inappbrowser on my sample  project created in phoneGap and where to paste the load remote page code?(i created sample project by following phonegap link you provided above ).

Comment: There is an install section on the inappbrowser, but basically run:
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

on the root of your phonegap project.

To use on index.js, inside the onDeviceReady() function run:
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open("the site url", "_blank", {});

You can set all the options specified in the inappbrowser link inside under the section "cordova.InAppBrowser.open" inside the {} object, for example { location: "no", zoom:"no" }